# Alarm Manager showing abnormality

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have set an Alarm Manager which will show Notification 10 seconds after app will be destroyed.

But it's not working.

**Here's my onDestroy() code:**

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, alarmManager.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10*1000, 10*1000, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

**and here is alarmManager.class:**

```
public class alarmManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, Notification.class);
           context.startService(service1);
    }

}
```

**and here is Notification.class:**

```
public class Notification extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
            = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        android.app.Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent,
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("It's been so Long!!!")
            .setSubText("Please return back to App")
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000,1000,1000,1000})
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Important Notification")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

*I've been working on this since many days, but I am unable to get through it.

Any Help would be highly* ***appreciated.***

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: __1)__ You don't need a Service. Create your notification in the BroadcastReceiver. __2)__ Don't use `setRepeating()` for the alarm; just `set()`. __3)__ Make sure your BroadcastReceiver is registered in the manifest. __4)__ Remove `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`. __5)__ You might consider removing the vibration and sound from the notification.

Comment: MikeM. nailed it. All his points are worth considering. Also the service you have started is going to remain active until the OS kills it. What you are probably looking to extend is `IntentService`, which will stop itself after executing, unlike a `Service`. But using either just to create a notification does not make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some relatively minor changes to make, but overall you've got the necessary code.

1. You don't need a `Service` for this. Move the code to create the `Notification` to the `BroadcastReceiver`, and replace `this` with `context` everywhere.
2. Make sure your `BroadcastReceiver` is listed in the manifest.
3. Don't use `setRepeating()` for the alarm; use `set()`. You only need it to fire once.
4. Remove the following line: `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`

Those are the changes necessary to get it working. However, you might also consider removing the sound and vibration from the `Notification`, and treat it more like a status message. It would also be preferable to rename your `BroadcastReceiver` class. Perhaps something like `AlarmReceiver`, to be in keeping with Java class naming conventions, and to avoid confusion with the `AlarmManager` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro. But bro here's a problem as i destroy the App, the notification comes instantly and also after 10 seconds. I want that Notification should repeat every 10 seconds after the App has been destroyed. Please help me with this also.

Comment: First of all, why would you want that? The notification will remain until the user selects it or clears it. Your users are going to hate your app if it makes their phones beep and buzz every 10 seconds they're not using your app.

Comment: Bro, actually I want to give an option to the user that at how much gap they want to be notified. for ex-after every 2 hours, or 4 hours. Please help on this. THANKS!..

Comment: Oh, ok, if you're just using 10 secs for testing, that makes more sense. You just need to use the `setRepeating()` method. The line you have in the posted code should do it.

Comment: Yeah i was using 10 secs for testing purpose only. Please can you tell me how to provide user with the option that when they want to notified, after 2 hours or 4 hours or 8 hours.

Comment: You'll want to use `SharedPreferences`. You'll have to post another question for that, though. Each question on Stack Overflow needs to be about a singular, specific issue.

Comment: Is this question OK??..[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728234/how-to-make-functioning-preference-screen?noredirect=1#comment38362559_24728234

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You're better off looking up a few tutorials for that so you can ask specific questions. Otherwise people are gonna downvote you and probably close the questions.

Comment: Bro, you have been really very cooperative. Can you please tell me the way of providing that option through mail. My email-id is hns.billionaires@gmail.com. Thanks!..

Comment: I wouldn't be of any help. I haven't done anything with Preference Screens. They seem like a pain in the butt to me.

Comment: Ok Bro, thanks for your continues replies and support so far. **Stay in Touch**

Comment: Hey, one more problem, as I am destroying the App the Notification is coming immediately and also after 10 secs. I want that Notification should be shown after 10 secs of App being destroyed. Please **Help** with this also.

Comment: If you're using `setRepeating()` the second parameter should be the delay in milliseconds. If you're on KitKat and it's still not working correctly, use `setExact()` instead.